# package:discovery does not find my ServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have created a custom Laravel package. Its hosted on a private repository.

When I try to install the package in a Laravel application like this:

```
composer require memberportal/congress-models
```

I get this error:

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Memberportal\CongressesModels\CMServiceProvider' not found  


Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I have double checked everything a hundred times, but I am clueless why he doesn't find the class `CMServiceProvider.php`.

Do I need to specify the provider anywhere else then in the `composer.json`?

This is the content of `composer.json` from my package:

```
{
    "name": "memberportal/congress-models",
    "description": "Takes care of the models between API and client",
    "type": "metapackage",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "My name",
            "email": "my@email.com"
        }
    ],
    "version" : "1.0",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "laracasts/presenter": "^0.2.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "orchestra/testbench": "^4.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
          "Memberportal\\CongressesModels\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
      "psr-4": {
          "Memberportal\\CongressesModels\\Tests\\": "tests"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Memberportal\\CongressesModels\\CMServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This is the folder structure:

[image]

This is the content of `CMServiceProvider.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Memberportal\CongressesModels;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CMServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../database/migrations');
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try the 'composer update' command?

Comment: @MehediHassan why should I do that? `composer update` works, but I am trying to install the new private package.

Comment: sometimes composer can't track/autoload the dependencies. That why sometimes, you need to re-update that. This basically happens when you work in a team. Your teammate may change the dependencies, and you add some.  There you might want to update the composer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to install a Laravel package your package type should be `package`. A `metapackage` is a package that [does not contain actual software, it simply depends on other packages to be installed](https://askubuntu.com/a/66268/247771).

In short, change

```
"type": "metapackage",
```

to

```
"type": "package",
```

and Laravel will find the service provider with auto-discovery when the package is required by composer.